# Deriving sine from cosine

Tags: trigonometry

If $\theta$ is an angle lying between $90^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ and $\cos(\theta) = - \frac{4}{5}$, why does this mean that $\sin(\theta) = \frac{3}{5}$?

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look at it specifically. If $$cos(\theta) = \frac{-4}{5}$$

That means the hypotenuse of your triangle is $5$ and the adjacent length is $4$ (on the negative x-axis)

Using Pythgorean's theorem: you get $a^2 = 25 - 16$
$$a^2 = 9$$
$$a = \pm 3$$

Since the angle $\theta$ lies between $90^{{\circ}}$ and $180^{{\circ}}$ that means your triangle lies in the second quadrant and $sin(\theta) \geq 0$ when it is in the second quadrant. Hence: $$sin(\theta) = \frac{3}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = 1$ and $\sin \theta>0 ,\space \theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$

Comment: Thanks.  How do you do it using associated acute angle?

Comment: What do you mean by the associated acute angle?

Answer (score 0):

You should know that $\sin (\theta)$ is positive for the values you give (sketch the graph if unsure) and that $$\sin^2 (\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$$ Which is the trigonometric form of Pythagoras' Theorem.